# block a request if the referer header is not equal to the domain

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-declarativenetrequest

How to block a request if the referer header is not equal to the domain from which the request is made? This needs to be done for extensions with Manifest version 3, using declarativeNetRequest.

```
const rules = blacklist.map((url, i) => {
            return {
              id: i + 1,
              priority: 1,
              action: {
                type: 'block',
              },
              condition: {
                urlFilter: url,
                excludedInitiatorDomains: [url],
                resourceTypes: ['script'],
              },
            }
          })

          chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
            removeRuleIds: rules.map(item => item.id),
            addRules: rules,
          })
```

Comment: There's no way to do it in declarativeNetRequest currently. You'll have to use ManifestV2 or install the extension via policies to enable it to use webRequestBlocking.